# Validation of a username with regex

Tags: ruby, regex

Trying to solve a regex sign-on problem. Here are the rules:

- Allowed characters are: lowercase letters, numbers, underscore.
- Length should be between 4 and 16 characters.

Here are the test cases it must pass:

```
Test.describe("Basic tests") do
  Test.assert_equals(validate_usr('asddsa'), true)
  Test.assert_equals(validate_usr('a'), false)
  Test.assert_equals(validate_usr('Hass'), false)
  Test.assert_equals(validate_usr('Hasd_12assssssasasasasasaasasasasas'), false)
  Test.assert_equals(validate_usr(''), false)
  Test.assert_equals(validate_usr('____'), true)
  Test.assert_equals(validate_usr('012'), false)
  Test.assert_equals(validate_usr('p1pp1'), true)
  Test.assert_equals(validate_usr('asd43 34'), false)
  Test.assert_equals(validate_usr('asd43_34'), true)
end
```

This is my code:

```
def validate_usr(username)
  if (username.length > 3 && username == username.downcase)
    return true
  elsif
    username.include?(" ") == true
    return false 
  else 
    return false
  end
end
```

Running into issues with the test case 9 that has a space involved. It returns `true`.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: you should make sure what he is asking before editing and imposing your interpretation of the question, really.

Answer (score 2):

Test case 9 returns `true` because it satisfies `username.length > 3 && username == username.downcase`. Note that `" ".downcase == " "` here.

Move that `return false if username.include?(" ")` up and it should work. I honestly suggest using `Regex` though.

```
def validate_usr(username)
  /\A[a-z0-9_]{4,16}\z/ === username
end
```

Comment: Don't forget to accept and/or vote up the answer if it helped ;) It's part of our motivation to help people here

Comment: Use `a !~ b`, not `!!(a =~ b)`.

Comment: @Jordan you have to write `!(a !~ b)` in this case. I think `!!(a =~ b)` looks better. But I get your point. Perhaps if you rename the method to `reject_usr` or something and return `a !~ b` that would be nice and concise.

Comment: Ah, my mistake. Poor reading comprehension—I didn't notice that OP was asserting equality to `true`/`false`, not truthiness/falsiness.